# Coupled non linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently trying to solve the following set of equations

$$\dot x=Ax(t)-Be^ty(t)$$
$$\dot y=Ay(t)-Be^{-t}x(t)$$
And when I enter it into mathematica it did not do anything

> DSolve[{x'[t] == 2*x[t] + 5 E^t y[t], 
>     y'[t] == 5 E^-t x[t] + 2*y[t]}, {x, y}, t]

Where I used A=2 and B=5.  Is there any analytical solution to this?

Comment: i think you must write $Exp[..]$

Comment: I used symbolic :ee:

Comment: there is an analytical solution and Maple found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple finds the solution.  If $r_1 = (2 A + 1 + \sqrt{4B^2+1})/2$ and
$r_2 = (2A+1-\sqrt{4B^2+1})/2$, 
$$ \eqalign{ x \left( t \right) &=c_1 e^{r_1 t} + c_2 e^{r_2 t}\cr y \left( t \right) &= - \dfrac{\sqrt{4B^2+1}+1}{2B} e^{(r_1 - 1) t} + \dfrac{\sqrt{4B^2+1}-1}{2B} e^{(r_2 - 1) t}}
$$